# very strange issue with "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: php, image, upload, load, mime

I checked lots of post about this problem but nothing matches with mine.

I was testing my project and I get this warning or error (I don't know exactly)

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

Some of the images from the same folder are loaded but some are not.

[THIS IS THE SITE](http://web-art.netau.net/) -an uploading site

10 min ago this problem wasn't, but now it appeared from nowhere.

Even on my computer where I tested this site hundreds of times.

And I'm sure this isn't a .htaccess problem.

What can I do about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing an image and sending it down as through `count.php`, but you've not changed the header to reflect the appropriate mime-type. You need to change the headers to reflect the type of content in the response itself.

Example:

I want to send a PNG file down through a PHP script, so I need to set the content-type to reflect this:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: I researched more and now I know that the problem occurs at the img.src in the javascript (I load some images with js).What's the problem with that?

Comment: @boyd What is the images source you're using?

Comment: it's the direct location of the image eg: files/images/1.jpg and img.src="files/images/1.jpg";

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but after I did intensive search in Google, the problem got solved. This tip might help for some of you who has the same problem.
I've fiddled with Apache httpd.conf file. Please go to the following section of the file:

```
</IfModule> mime_module>
#
# TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
# filename extension to MIME-type.
#
TypesConfig conf/mime.types

#
# AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
# file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
#
#AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
#
# AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
# information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
#
#AddEncoding x-compress .Z
#AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
#
# If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
# probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

#
# AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
# actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
# or added with the Action directive (see below)
#
# To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
# (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

# For type maps (negotiated resources):
#AddHandler type-map var

#
# Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
#
# To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
# (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
#
#AddType text/html .shtml
#AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml



</IfModule>
```

make sure adding the following AddTypes was included in the above module WITHOUT POUND(#)KEY. please do not use # key in front of any of the following AddTypes when you adding them within the module that way Apache server will read them:

```
AddType image/gif .gif

AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg

AddType image/png .png
```

Comment: So this will work only on my server right?(because I modify my httpd.conf file). How can I make it work on every server?